# Google maps inside canvas object

Tags: html, google-maps, html5-canvas

is it possible to get google maps inside a canvas object? So if I draw say a triangle the map would only show up inside it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

yes it is possible

http://googlemapsmania.blogspot.com/2011/04/using-canvas-with-google-maps.html

http://econym.org.uk/gmap/

Comment: Hey, I do not mean to put a canvas ON a map, but to put the map INSIDE a canvas to have it in a different form but a square. I want a map that is basically a square rotated by 45°.

Comment: So you are saying it can not be done?
I do need to eb able to plot stuff on a google map and afterwards transform it by putting it into a canvas. I figured, since it is possible to transform videos like this http://beta.theexpressiveweb.com/#!/html5-video one could also do that with google maps?

Answer (score 0):

Suppose we have a div with id = "map" and within it we have our map:

Supongamos que tenemos un div con id = "map" y dentro de él, nuestro mapa:

```
#map {
    transform: rotate(-10deg);
}
```

Simple, effective. :)

Simple, efectivo :)